# Pre-Built Intents for Watson Conversation

Tags: watson-conversation

After setting up the IBM Watson Conversation service on my [Raspberry Pi](http://www.instructables.com/id/Build-a-Talking-Robot-With-Watson-and-Raspberry-Pi/) today I was disappointed to see that I'd have to write out every possible input (intent) and output (entity). Chalk this up to my extreme naivety around machine learning, **But isn't there a way to tie into an existing set of conversation capabilities?**

For example, I'm sure Watson already knows all the words for Hello and their proper responses. Or how to answer a variety of silly questions. Is there any way to tap into the Watson [we all saw on Jeopardy](https://youtu.be/P18EdAKuC1U)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want to spend millions of dollars, you can get a license to All Of Watson. For what you are using, 'watson' is just a brand name, and it has what capabilities it has.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of options here.

**System Entities**

These are pre-defined to allow you to understand certain common concepts. Numbers, Currency and Dates are the available ones at the moment, but there are more coming.

**Entites**

You can also pull public lists and import as CSV. For example: http://data.okfn.org/data/core/country-list . You may need to check the licensing before using though.

**Intents**

As you mentioned there is no pre-defined intents. But there are two solutions available that augment conversation.

First is "[Watson Virtual Agent](https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/cognitive-customer-engagement)". This is a SaaS that contains pre-defined training sets for certain industries, as well as custom UI you can slot into your application. It's not cheap, but you can get a trial to play with it.

The other option is "[Project Intu](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/project-intu.html)". It's still experimental, but it's purpose is to help in building robots/IOT devices. It contains pre-defined chit chat and some off topic stuff.

They have a "[TJ Bot](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/research/2016/11/calling-makers-meet-tj-bot/)" project which can be used with a raspberry pi.